# SQL UPDATE function syntax error

Tags: sql

I am attempting to write an UPDATE function based on values that will be input into dropdown boxes and text boxes by a user

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Prices_Click()
Dim SQL_string As String

SQL_string = _
"UPDATE tblPrice " & _
    "SET [P/N] = " & Me.txtPartNumber.Column(0) & ", " & _
    "Type = " & Me.txtPriceType.Column(0) & ", " & _
    "Region = " & Me.txtRegion.Column(0) & ", " & _
    "Price = " & Me.txtPrice.Value & ", " & _
    "WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID.Value & ";"



DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_string

End Sub
```

I keep getting a syntax error in the UPDATE function and I'm not sure where it is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove that extra comma before  WHERE.

Comment: Use parameters.  Don't munge strings by stuffing parameters in them.  Instead use parameters properly so you don't get unexpected syntax errors.